# help about authentication with claims - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wcf

i need more information about an error in sharepoint server 2010, in based your post: 
SharePoint 2010 - The Security Token Service is not available, in my IIS look at configurations is enable 32-bits Application in false, my machine is windows 2008 r2 64-bits Operative System and Sql server 2008 r2 with service pack 2 64-bits! 
others persons you help with this solution, for example me! 
excuse me, for my regular english i study basic skill for your language. 
Good day!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the article [Configure the security token service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806864.aspx)

If you are still facing the issue.. you can check the ULS logfile i.e. psconfig file and see any detailed stack exception.